# How do I download apps in ipad mini ios9.3.6

Tags: ipad

I known my ipad is old version.but im  trying to download apps from app store .but the apps are incompatible to the ipad..is there any other way to still get apps in my ipad???

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to download older versions of an app from the iOS App Store, but you must already have "bought" (or used "Get" for a free app) the app using the Apple ID used by your older iPad.

Once the app is registered as Purchased (Apple calls it this even if it's a free app) against your Apple ID, you can go into the Purchased tab on the App Store on your older iPad and download from there.

You will get a pop-up "Download an older version of this app?" ("The current version requires iOS X.X or later, but you can download the latest compatible version") where you choose Download.

So to be able to do this, if you haven't already got the app, you do need a second iOS device using the same Apple ID for the App Store.

Comment: As additional info, the developer of that specific app might not support the older version and/or have removed the older version from distribution on the App Store.  I've seen this happen multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to do this unless you jailbreak the iPad. All iOS/iPadOS products must run apps only from the App Store.